# Graphics (java.awt.Graphics) not working on call

Tags: java, swing, graphics, awt

I am new to programming in Java, but I have coded in other languages. I've got a problem whereby I am unable to call my `Paint()` method which contains some drawing instructions. I want to be able to call it inside a timer function. The code's bellow:

```
package main;

import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.awt.event.KeyEvent;
import java.awt.event.KeyListener;
import java.util.Timer;
import java.util.TimerTask;
import java.awt.Canvas;

import javax.swing.JPanel;

public class Player extends JPanel implements KeyListener, ActionListener{
    // does the same as inheritiing methods and attributes from "JPanel" class type.

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    private static long UUID; 
    // Time to set game-state values
    @SuppressWarnings("unused")
    private boolean isPlaying = false;
    private int startingScore = 0;
    @SuppressWarnings("unused")
    private int currScore = startingScore;

    // currScore should equal startingScore for correct start score when starting each game.
    @SuppressWarnings("unused")
    private int TotalBricks = 21;
    private static Timer timer = new Timer();
    private int delay = 5;

    // Player Start Pos
    private int PlayerX = 310;
    private int PlayerY = 550; // TODO Change PlayerY Value

    // Player Dimensions from Start Coords
    private int PlayerMinX = PlayerX - 50;
    private int PlayerMaxX = PlayerX + 50;
    private int PlayerMinY = PlayerY - 4;
    private int PlayerMaxY = PlayerY + 4;

    // Ball Start Pos
    @SuppressWarnings("unused")
    private int BallX = 120;
    @SuppressWarnings("unused")
    private int BallY = 350;

    // Ball Velocities
    @SuppressWarnings("unused")
    private int BallVelX = -1;
    @SuppressWarnings("unused")
    private int BallVelY = -2;

    public Player(){
        super();
        this.setBackground(Color.white);
        addKeyListener(this);
        setFocusable(true);
        setFocusTraversalKeysEnabled(false);
        setVisible(true);
        MyTimer();

        //TODO  Get the bricks to display on screen
    }

    public void MyTimer() {
        TimerTask timerTask;

        timerTask = new TimerTask() {
            @Override
            public void run() { 
                while (true) {
                    // TODO Get Paint() function working in here
                }
            }
        };
         timer.schedule(timerTask, 0, delay);
    }

    public void Paint(Graphics g){
        // linear functions - colour precedes draw, can be overriden without affecting previous statements
        // background
        g.setColor(Color.black);
        g.fillRect(1, 1, 692, 592);

        // border of window
        g.setColor(Color.yellow);
        g.fillRect(0,0,3,592);
        g.fillRect(0,0,692,3);
        g.fillRect(691,0,3,592);

        // no underside border

        // paddle settings
        g.setColor(Color.green);
        g.fillRect(PlayerMinX, PlayerMinY, PlayerMaxX, PlayerMaxY);
        //TODO Check if this works

        // ball settings
        g.setColor(Color.yellow);
        g.fillRect(BallX, BallY, 20, 20);
    }

    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
    }

    public void keyPressed(KeyEvent arg0) {
        if (arg0.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_RIGHT)
        {
        }
        else if (true){
        }
    }

    public void keyReleased(KeyEvent arg0) {}

    public void keyTyped(KeyEvent arg0) {} 
}
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Also, any tips you guys could provide would also help. Thanks for any help you can provide in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Custom painting is done by overriding `paintComponent(...)` not paint(...). You also need to invoke `super.paintComponent(g)` as the first statement to make sure the background get painted.
2. Java is case sensitive, so you need to make sure you override the proper method. You should always use `@Override` on the line before the method you override. If you make a typing error the compiler will tell you.
3. You should be using a `Swing Timer` for animation. Updates to Swing components should be done on the Event Dispatch Thread (EDT). The Swing Timer will automatically execute the code on the EDT.
4. Don't use a `while (true)` loop in the Timer. The point of using a Timer is that the Timer becomes the loop. You just execute your code every time the Timer fires.
5. In the `ActionListener` of your Timer you change the value of your variables to provide the animation and then you invoke `repaint()` which will cause your panel to be repainted.
6. Variable names should NOT start with an upper case character. Notice how the forums highlights your variable names because it thinks they are class names. This is confusing. Learn Java conventions and follow them.
7. Read the [Swing Tutorial](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/TOC.html) for Swing basics. There are section on a) `Concurrency in Swing` b) `How to Use Swing Timers` c) `Custom Painting`.

Comment: Thanks for you're response, but if you could provide code extracts so that I can learn from them apply it correctly. Thanks, Jerry

Comment: @JerryPlayz101, I did provide code extracts. The tutorial has working examples. You learn by reading and playing with working examples. If there is something you don't understand about the tutorial demos then ask a follow up question. You can also search the forum for other examples since you know now the proper painting method to override.